# Sum of Numeric Values In Alphanumeric Column

Tags: excel, excel-formula

In Column L of an excel sheet I have values like following starting from L4

```
0.16Km
5.98Km
29.32Km
45.27Km
7.38Km
4.05Km
1.05Km
4.69Km
0.49Km
18.71Km
0Km
```

I am trying to get the sum of numeric values by using following but it doesn't work

```
=SUM(VALUE(LEFT(L4:L14,LEN(L4:L14)-2)))
```

What Am I missing?
I just want the sum total of the numbers.

Comment: Shouldn't you only sum if the Unit of measure is the same? or are they all KM and you could simply sum by replacing the KM with '' and then sum?

Answer (score 5):

Either array enter your formula:

```
=SUM(VALUE(LEFT(L4:L14,LEN(L4:L14)-2)))
```

By confirming with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.  If done correctly then Excel will put `{}` around the formula.

Or

Use SUMPRODUCT() instead of SUM():

```
=SUMPRODUCT(VALUE(LEFT(L4:L14,LEN(L4:L14)-2)))
```

And enter normally.

[image]

Comment: what would happen if 1 of the entries was 10m? :P  hoping they are all the same unit of measure!

Comment: And yes, none of the records will be anything different from Km as last two characters.

Comment: @rusticnomad this is why one should put the numbers in one column and the unit of measure in the next.

Comment: @barryhoudini custom formatting makes it hard for excel formulas to determine units what units are being used.  if units are in a separate column you can do a check and apply a factor with a simple if formula.  That has just been my experience with the two options.

Comment: OK, but surely that would be standard practice with currency - formatting that displays $ or £ - why is km any different?

Comment: @barryhoudini you may want to add the tag with whom you are arguing.  I am in agreement with you, but I doubt Forward Ed will see it after 3 hours.

Answer (score 3):

If all kms you could perhaps use `SUBSTITUTE` function like this

`=SUMPRODUCT(SUBSTITUTE(L4:L14,”Km”,””)+0)`